# Data binding not working for model property in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to put an Angular application together as I am learning. I am having trouble using data binding with a model property.

I have a model: announcer.model.ts

```
export class Announcer{
    constructor(public name: string){}
  }
```

I import the model in the register.component.ts:

```
import { Announcer} from '../models/announcer.model'

  ....some code omited

announcer: Announcer
loading: Boolean

 constructor(private http: Http) { }

ngOnInit() {
       this.getRegister(); //I use this code to set the announcer variable
}


getRegister() : void
{
     this.loading= true;
     this.http.request('http://www.example.com/apiannouncer/show/0').subscribe((res: Response) => {
     var result = res.json();



     this.announcer= new Announcer(result.name);
    this.loading= false;
 } )
```

}

In the template of the register.component.ts I can't use this:

```
 <div> {{ announcer.name }} </div>
```

I get this message:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error class - inline template:2:5 caused by: self.context.announcer is undefined
```

Comment: are you using controllerAs syntax?

Comment: I believe I am not.

Comment: Did you try using the `?` operator as in `<div> {{ announcer?.name }} </div>` ?

Comment: The question mark did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `controllerAs` syntax in your views, take a look at [here](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/#controllers-as-classes) and [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController).

change your template to this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as vm"
     <div> {{ announcer.name }} </div>
 </div>
```

what it does is simply put an instance of your class in `$scope` and make that class available in `$scope` via `vm`.